# Java Codec API to convert JPEG frames/images to MPEG video

Tags: java, image-processing

I need your help & wisdom for selecting a Java Media Codec Library.

**Requirements:**

1. Codec most be 100% Java implementation (No native dependencies)
2. Codec most be able to convert JPEG images to all MPEG video formats
3. Codec most be free for development and free to get developers API
4. Codec API most still have an active project/community with easy access to documentation & examples
5. Optional – Free to distribute (Actually its ok if the API will require a small license 
   fee for commercial use ) Small means less than 10 USD, my research shows that MPEG codes are around 5-6 USD per user.

**Issues with popular libraries that I have tried:**

1. JMF

• Does not support conversion(write, only read) to MPEG video , please see supported formats(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html)

2. Xuggler

• No longer active project , sparse documentation that is no longer maintained, please see no longer active

3. JavaCV (Java Wrapper around OpenCV C/C++)

• Not purely Java - Requires 32 bit or 64 bit components -

Any help will be appreciated, please only suggest if requirements 1 to 4 are met, requirement 5 is optional.

Thank you again.